# Obter informações sobre função em Lua

Tags: lua

Como poderia ter informações sobre funções globais em um arquivo .lua?

```
function showAll(arg1, arg2)
    return print(arg1, arg2)
end
```

Tipo, ter informações sobre argumentos, etc.

Comment: a documentação lua https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html#1

Comment: aqui vc encontra mais informações sobre funções https://www.lua.org/pil/5.html

Comment: Tem uma otima resposta aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907169/global-function-in-lua

Comment: Qual problema você quer resolver com essa informação?

Answer (score 0):

Uma amostra de como isso é feito:

En global.lua (onde a função global está locada) :

```
globalFunction1 = function(params)
    print("Eu sou globalFunction1")
end
```

a chamada da funcao, outrofile.lua :

```
globalFunction1(params)
```